# tryCatch() in across() fails when the error comes from another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I use `across()` and I want to put `NA` where the computation fails. I tried to use `tryCatch()` but can't make it work in my case, whereas there are situations where it works.

This works:

```r
library(dplyr)
head(mtcars) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      all_of("drat"),
      function(x) tryCatch(blabla, error = function(e) NA) # create an intentional error for the example
    )
  )
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110   NA 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110   NA 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93   NA 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110   NA 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175   NA 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105   NA 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

But this doesn't:

```r
library(dplyr)
head(mtcars) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      all_of("drat"),
      function(x) tryCatch(x[which(mpg == 10000)], error = function(e) NA) # create an intentional error for the example
    )
  )
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
#> Caused by error in `across()`:
#> ! Problem while computing column `drat`.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I thought `tryCatch()` was supposed to catch any error. Why doesn't it work in the second situation? How to fix it?

Note: I need to use `across()` in my real situation (even if it's not truly needed in the examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the `tryCatch` because the code you run doesn't trigger an error. Basically you are running

```
foo <- function(x) tryCatch(x[which(mtcars$mpg==10000)], error = function(e) NA))
foo(mtcars$drat)
# numeric(0)
```

And notice that no error is triggered. That expression simply returns `numeric(0)`. And the problem is that the function needs to return a value with a non-zero length. So the error is happening after your `tryCatch` code runs and dplyr is trying to assign the value back into the data.frame. You will need to handle the case where no values are found separately. Perhaps

```
head(mtcars) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      all_of("drat"),
      function(x) {
        matches <- mpg == 10000
        if (any(matches)) x[which(matches)] else NA
      }
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to reference `mpg` with `x`:

```r
library(dplyr)

head(mtcars) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      all_of("drat"),
      function(x) tryCatch(x[which(x$mpg == 10000)], error = function(e) NA) # create an intentional error for the example
    )
  )
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110   NA 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110   NA 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93   NA 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110   NA 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175   NA 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105   NA 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works how you expect. The code you've written is invalid so it triggers the error. When you use `across()`, your function will receive a vector. So in this case `x` is a numeric vector and `x$mpg` will trigger an error since `x` is not a data.frame. So basically you are just introducing a case that will always throw an error so NA will always be returned.